# Putting entries from a textfield into a mysql Database

Tags: php, sql, insert, backend, textfield

I'm new in PHP and trying operate with a database.

First i want that my "users" are able to store their entries in a Database. Of course I'm the admin of the DB.

the problem ist, whenever I push the Button "Anmelden" , just NULL values are stored in my DB.

The problem I guess is, that the input of textarea "username" and "pw" in my index.php are not transferred into my signup1.php script.

So, I got 2 Skripts (index.php, signup1.php). My previous attempt is here

This is my index.php file:

```
<?php


//path of signup1.php: '/users/giacumo/include/signup1.php'

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="/users/giacumo/include/signup1.php" method="POST">

   <input type = "text" name = "username" placeholder = "username">
   <input type = "text" name = "pw" placeholder = "pw">
   <button type = "submit" name = "submit">Anmelden</button>    

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my signup1.php skript

```
$server = "";
$user = "";
$datenbankname = "";
$tabellenname = "";
$password = '';

$verbindung = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $password, $datenbankname);

?>

<?php

    $nameofuser = $_POST['username'];
    $passwordofuser = $_POST['pw'];

    $abfrage1 = "Insert into datas (username, pw)
    VALUES ('$nameofuser' , '$passwordofuser');";   
    mysqli_query($verbindung, $abfrage1);


    header('Location: ../include/index.php?signup=success');



?>
```

When I try this in a local way everything works, but when I e.g. Hosting this as a Website, then this doesen't works because any reason.

I'm totally in struggle, cause I tried lots of things. I'd be grateful if someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

Okey, i did it by myself. Anyhow the problem is because of the specification of the path in my fdp server.

So the Code is quite okey.